# Software/apparatus to measure wavelength of visible light

Tags: visible-light, resource-recommendations, software, wavelength

I need a software or an apparatus (avaiable in school conditions) to measure wavelengths of visible light. In my lab I use coloured filters to get different colours of light, but I have to measure exact wavelenths.

Answer (score 3):

This depends largely on what apparatus your school already has.  But every school should have a good diffraction grating and a large white screen.  You can then do a diffraction experiment and take measurements on the screen.  Then using the formula  $d \ sin \theta =n \lambda$, you can get wavelengths.  See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/gratcal.html for more information on measuring wavelengths using a diffraction grating.

This method will probably not give you extremely precise results but should work fairly well.  Do ask your school if they have any useful software for this purpose.

Comment: A diffraction grating is the *de rigueur* tool for a moderate precision wavelength measurement. But why would you be bothered about *software* for the job?

Comment: Vanja Is this what you want? Note that a direct measurement of visible light never was done, there is only a relation to the intensity distributions on an observers screen, produced by the deflection of light at sharp edges.

Comment: @dmckee. Software which displays graphs of intensity against position would make measurements more accurate and will also make life easier for us.